# Wait for requests done by AsyncHTTPClient in Tornado

Tags: python, tornado

I'm trying to have use PeriodicCallback calling my function every X seconds, but it seems that because AsyncHTTPClient has its own ioloop it doesn't not block it from running again without waiting for the previous result.

Example:

```
import os, json, time, tornado.ioloop, tornado.web
from tornado import gen
from tornado.ioloop import PeriodicCallback
from tornado.httpclient import AsyncHTTPClient, HTTPClient, HTTPRequest, HTTPError

http_client = AsyncHTTPClient()
index = 0

@gen.coroutine
def loop():
    global index
    print "ENTER", index
    try:
        response = yield http_client.fetch("https://httpbin.org/delay/5")
        result = json.loads(response.body)
    except HTTPError as e:
        print("Error: " + str(e))
        raise
    finally:
        print "EXIT", index
        index += 1
        raise gen.Return(result)

def ready():
    global index
    index = 0
    print "START"
    callback = PeriodicCallback(loop, 1000) # every second
    callback.start()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = tornado.web.Application([])
    app.listen(8888)

    current_ioloop = tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current()
    current_ioloop.spawn_callback(ready)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

What I expected:

```
START
ENTER 0
EXIT 0
ENTER 1
EXIT 1
...
```

What I got:

```
START
ENTER 0
ENTER 0
ENTER 0
ENTER 0
ENTER 0
ENTER 0
EXIT 0
ENTER 1
EXIT 1
ENTER 2
EXIT 2
ENTER 3
EXIT 3
ENTER 4
EXIT 4
ENTER 5
```

Answer (score 1):

PeriodicCallback and coroutines don't work very well together, as you have observed. Better to *not* use PeriodicCallback and just implement a loop directly with a coroutine:

```
@gen.coroutine
def ready():
    global index
    index = 0
    print "START"
    while True:
        result = yield loop()
        # Do something with the result
        print result
```

See the Tornado documentation on this subject:

http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/guide/coroutines.html?highlight=periodiccallback#running-in-the-background

Comment: You probably want to add a `yield gen.sleep(datetime.timedelta(seconds=1))` in that loop. Or at the start of the loop do `next_time = IOLoop.current().time()` and at the end `yield gen.sleep(next_time)`. The second form will try to stay on a 1-second interval no matter how long the function takes.